# How do I use app.get to route to a new page on Nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, express

I've been trying to use app.get to route to a new html page like so:
e.g. when I type localhost:3000/newpage i want it to route to newpage.html

I've only been able to route to another JS file through app.get. Is it possible to do this but instead route to a html file? If not, is there a more appropriate method to doing this? I'm new to nodejs so any help at all would help!

What I have currently
app.js

```
var graball = require('./public/javascripts/graball')
app.get('/graball', function (req, res) {
  res.send(ibm);
});
```

What I want
app.js

```
var page = require('./public/page1'); //page1.html
app.get('/page1', function(req, res) {
   res.send(page1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`sendFile`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendFile):

```
app.get('/sitemap',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile('/sitemap.html');
});
```

Comment: I knew I overlooked something simple. Thank you!